# pixi-essentials/SVG libtess.js library is undefined when I use SvgScene

Tags: typescript, svg, game-development, pixi.js

Types of the library seem to not be recognized from typescript.
[here is the error in chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjBMn.png)

Comment: The types themselves don't have any bearing on what gets run in the browser. Your error indicates that you're actually trying to set a value on an undefined object. If you add some code we might be able to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the libtess library itself. What fixed it was wraping the .min.js file like this:

```
var libtess = (function() {
...
return this.libtess;
}).apply(new Object());
```